# Photoshop - Is it possible to have text overflow ellipsis

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm inserting data from variables and I would like text that is too long to get truncated with an ellipsis. Example if the string is:
"This is an example string" but the word "string" overflows outside of the text box is puts "This is an example ..."

Is this possible in photoshop or no?

Comment: I don't think so without scripting. You can easily via scripting.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the reply... that's the conclusion i came to